# What is the difference between Devil's Food and Chocolate cake?

Tags: cake

I always thought they were (perhaps regionally) different labels for the same cake. While at a local fair, I noticed that there were separate categories for Devil's Food and Chocolate cake.

Comment: I've always wondered this!  Can't wait to see a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PracticallyEdible](http://www.practicallyedible.com/edible.nsf/pages/devilsfoodcake) has a nice description of Devil's Food Cake.

Originally, Devil's Food Cake had a medium dense texture.  The colour had a reddish tint that was probably caused by baking soda reacting with cocoa powder.  In fact, I have an old cookbook (The Day by Day Cook Book, 1939) that contains a recipe for Red Devil's Food Cake.  This recipe calls for 2 oz. unsweetened chocolate and 1 tsp. of baking soda.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_food_cake)

> Devil's food cake is generally more
>   moist and airy than other chocolate
>   cakes, and often uses cocoa  as
>   opposed to chocolate for the flavor as
>   well as coffee.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_food_cake)  The lack of melted
>   chocolate and the addition of coffee
>   is typically what distinguishes a
>   'devil's food cake' from a chocolate
>   cake, though some recipes call for
>   all, resulting in an even richer
>   chocolate flavor.